# Checking if the remaining input is whitespace with parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm trying out the parsec library and I'm not sure how to handle this basic task.

Suppose I have the following:

```
data Foo = A | AB
```

and I want the string "a" to be parsed as `A` and "a b" `AB`.  If I just do this:

```
parseA :: parser Foo
parseA = do
           reserved "a"
           return A

parseAB :: parser Foo
parseAB = do
            reserved "a"
            reserved "b"
            return AB

parseFoo :: parser Foo
parseFoo =  parseA
        <|> parseAB
```

then `parseFoo` will parse "a b" as `A` since `parseA` doesn't care that there is non-whitespace still left after consuming the 'a'.  How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change grammar to `AB | A` and use `try` from parsec, which gives lookahead capability to your parser.

This should work

```
parseFoo = try Parse AB <|> parse A
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that my `parseAB` works fine, it's `parseFoo` that I'm having issues with.

Comment: ah, got it. your grammar needs backtracking

Comment: you need to change grammar to AB | A and use `try` from parsec

Comment: this does work for my purposes, but now I'm wondering how one might prevent the string "a b c" from parsing as `AB`?  Essentially, I want the parse to fail if there is remaining non-whitespace text.

Comment: You can definitely do it in parsec but the bigger problem might be defining your grammar completely first